# Why my browser is closing automatically before execute entire selenium code?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, browser, automation

I'm studying web automation with python and selenium and created a code to insert a value in a input text.

Here's my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='APjFqb']")

input.send_keys("Test")
```

The code should open the browser and insert "Test" on the input, however the page closes before set the value.

Same thing happened with Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably shouldn't be using `input`, as that is a reserved method in Python.

You probably shouldn't be using `ChromeDriverManager` either, as selenium now includes Selenium Manager with it.

And that looks like an autogenerated selector, which means it may change every time you load that page. Use `(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[name="q"]')` instead on the Google page.

If you want your script to stop at the end of your test, put in a `breakpoint()` on the last line. To continue from the program when stopped at a breakpoint, type `c` and press Enter.

Here's everything together:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://google.com")
search_bar = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[name="q"]')
search_bar.send_keys("selenium github")
search_bar.submit()
breakpoint()
driver.quit()
```

For more reliability, you could use `WebDriverWait` to wait for elements before interacting with them. More info: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/

Comment: Thank you! It really worked as I expected.